# Python: class with double underscore

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, private

I'm following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/820410) and trying to make a singleton class using Metaclass. But, I want to make some internal tweaks to this singleton class and want the users to use another class (let's call it `MySingleton(__Singleton)`). So I decided to make it private but it gives the following error.

[image]

My sole purpose is to prevent `__Singleton` from being used outside. How can I achieve this?

On a separate note, is it a good practice to use double underscore with classes?

Comment: You want to prevent `__Singleton` from being used outside of what?

Comment: Outside of my module. Only `MySingleton` should be accessible for anyone who wants to use this.

Comment: Leading double underscores are not a general-purpose privacy marker. They don't make things any more private than single underscores.

Comment: basically, the name is mangled. So, the friction to use this is more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the class, the identifier `__Singleton` is getting [mangled](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).  You end up having problems because name mangling only happens inside classes (not outside).  So `__Singleton` as a class name means something different than `__Singleton` when you are inside a class suite.

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. **This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.**

Note that the primary reason for mangling is because it

> ... is helpful for letting subclasses override methods without breaking intraclass method calls.

Also:

> ... to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses

As such, there really isn't any reason to have a class with leading double underscores in the name (there is no chance of intraclass method calls having conflicts with class names).  A single leading underscore is a good enough signal to users that they shouldn't use that class:

> ... a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. `_spam`) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). **It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.**

---

I wouldn't advise it, but if you *really* want it to work, you can probably use `globals` to look up the class:

```
class __Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(globals()['__Foo'], self).__init__()

f = __Foo()
print f
```

Comment: Why is it unadvisable?

Comment: @PankajSinghal -- It's a lot of extra typing and weird (somewhat confusing and inefficient) introspection for absolutely no gain...

Answer (score 1):

Every name inside a class definition with two leading underscores is mangled, so `__Singleton` becomes `_Singleton__Singleton`. To make clear, that some class is not supposed to be used publicly use **one** underscore.

Comment: even `_Singleton__Singleton` is not working. just try it out

Comment: Did you really tried `class _Singleton__Singleton(type): ...`?

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have [private variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private); they are all accessible externally.

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

The Python Cookbook provides a [Singleton class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/412551-simple-singleton/) that can be inherited by other classes to become Singletons.